# Validating login dialog using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I need some help with validation using ajax. My login dialog works but it does not handle what happens on succes or validation errors are present. I am not sure how or where I actually create the ajax post (I am not experienced with jquery/Ajax)

This is my view
    
        @model Models.LoginModel

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
    }

    <hgroup class="title">
    @*    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>*@
    </hgroup>

    <section id="loginForm" style="margin-left: 20px; border-width: 0px;">

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { Id = "login_form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Log in Form</legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
                </li>
            </ol>


        </fieldset>
        @*<p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") if you don't have an account.
        </p>*@
    }
    </section>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dlgLogin").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: true,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: true,
            title: "Login",

            buttons: {
                Login: function () {
                    $("#login_form").submit();

                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });


    });
</script>
```

This is my loginpost method in my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                return Json(new { success = true });   
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return PartialView("LoginDialog",model);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, on your form declaration, this needs to be:

```
new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "loginForm" }
```

As it doesn't know what to replace on submit.

As an aside: IMHO, I think your results should be the same, i.e. If you are going to return views, return views, if you are dealing in JSON, only deal in JSON. If you simply want to close the dialog on success, create a view called Success, return it on success and implant the necessary JavaScript to do that in that view.

Returning different types of views will just mean a whole bunch of extra flow statements on the client side. Does that make sense?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've managed to get it working myself. But thanks for the reply

Comment: Are your scripts all working after a validation error? I won't bang on about it (after this!), but if you use the conventions of returning views rather than mixed results, you wouldn't need all of that script. Either way, glad you're sorted.

Comment: Yes they do work. Thanks for asking. But what do you mean when you say "but if you use the conventions of returning views rather than mixed results". Could you give an example of this?

Comment: I just noticed that if I have multiple validation errors, another dialog box will show. This does not happen when there is only one validation error

Comment: My pleasure. Did you end up returning the views only, rather than JSON/View dependent upon condition? IMO MVC is only ever tricky when you are trying to bend the conventions to your will, rather than ride the wave of conventions to an ultimate win, ha! I have a mantra to my developers: in MVC if you're struggling to get something working, you may be approaching it from the wrong angle.

Comment: I decided to return only JSON for the moment. It will likely have to change to views later but I run into the issue of having multiple dialog's opened whenever a ModelState.Add occurs in my controller when returning a view and a model.

Comment: You probably need to move your form section into its own view. That way your UpdateTargetId is only updating the form and its validation summary, rather than all of the associated script into the browser multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

t

I have solved my problem myself. Here is the code. Is it possible to put the .ajax function in the same script that creates the dialog box?

```
<div id="dlgLogin">
        @model Models.LoginModel

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
        }

        <hgroup class="title">
        @*    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>*@
        </hgroup>

        <section id="loginForm" style="margin-left: 20px; border-width: 0px;">

        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { Id = "login_form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Log in Form</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Log in" style="display:none"/>

            </fieldset>
            @*<p>
                @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") if you don't have an account.
            </p>*@
        }
        </section>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dlgLogin").dialog({
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: true,
                draggable: true,
                resizable: true,
                title: "Login",

                buttons: {
                    Login: function () {
                        $("#login_form").submit();

                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });


        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {    
            $('#login_form').on('submit', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.success) {
                            // We have a JSON object in case of success              
                            $('#dlgLogin').dialog("close");

                        } else {
                            // We have the partial with errors in case of failure
                            // so all we have to do is update the DOM

                            $('#dlgLogin').html(result);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```